# How to change element value in ArrayNode

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this file (example.json):

```json
{
    "messages" : [ "msg 1", "msg 2", "msg 3" ],
}
```

Then I create a `JsonNode` like this:

```java
BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("example.json"));
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(fileReader);
```

How do I change the array element value from  "msg 1" to "msg 1A" without removing the element and adding a new one with value "msg 1A"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to change first element of the `messages` array, use following code:

```
((ArrayNode) rootNode.withArray("messages")).set(0, new TextNode("msg 1A"));
```

**UPD**

Another version, which removes and then inserts element (that is what you try to avoid):

```
((ArrayNode) rootNode.withArray("messages")).remove(0);
((ArrayNode) rootNode.withArray("messages")).insert(0, new TextNode("msg 1A"));
```

Comment: Yes,, can do that. But that is actually what I not did want to do,, remove the element,, and add a new.

Comment: @lg.lindstrom actually, that is exactly what you want: my code changes the element. You can check that using source code of `ArrayNode` (which is backed up by `ArrayList`).

Comment: uhhh,, I see the difference. I try it out.

Comment: @lg.lindstrom I understood what you meant. You cannot change the message itself in-place, because every array element is a `TextNode`, which is immutable.

Comment: okey. I understand. This is not what I hoped for,, but a answer *smile*